# Java Object Referencing

Tags: java, object, reference

Why am I getting an object resolution error in this code?  The error occurs in the for loop regarding 'displayObject.ob1':

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class drawr extends JPanel{

    public static int animationSpeed=470;
    public static int diameter = 50;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#ffc000"));
        g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for(int cnt=0; cnt/2<=displayObject.ob1.noOfVerts; cnt+=2){
            g.drawLine(displayObject.ob1.coord[cnt], displayObject.ob1.coord[cnt+1], ob1.coord[cnt+2], ob1.coord[cnt+3]);
        }
}
```

The object is instanciated here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass{

    public static final int windowWidth = 1280;
    public static final int windowHeight = 640;
    public static boolean crash = false;

    public static displayObject ob1, ob2, ob3;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException {

        String colorString="#ff0000";
        int ob1verts[]={10,10,50,50,30,80};
        displayObject ob1=new displayObject("#ff0000", ob1verts);
    }
}
```

And constructed here:

```
public class displayObject {

    //  Each object is defined by a color, number of vertices, and dim (2,3,4) coordinate vertex locations
    //  Use dim to verify that the right number of vertices were sent

        public static int dim=2;

        public String color;
        public int noOfVerts;
        public int coords [];

        public displayObject (String col, int verts[]){

            if (verts.length%dim != 0){
                System.out.printf ("Crap in!");
                return;
            }
            this.coords=new int[verts.length+2];
            color=col;
            noOfVerts=verts.length/dim;
            for (int cnt=0; cnt<verts.length; cnt++){
                coords[cnt]=verts[cnt];
            }
            coords[verts.length]=verts[0];  //make last vertex equal first to close the shape
            coords[verts.length+1]=verts[1];
        }       
}
```

Comment: In Java, classes should be named in `PascalCase`. Deviating from this convention makes your code very hard to read; and it also plays havoc with the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Please include the actual error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the fact that your code is a mess, this line

```
displayObject ob1 = new displayObject("#ff0000", ob1verts);
```

should simply be:

```
ob1 = new displayObject("#ff0000", ob1verts);
```

You have declared ob1, ob2 & ob3 in the code, i.e.

```
public static displayObject ob1, ob2, ob3; // ob1 declared
```

As for your error, *ob1* is **not** a static variable of the `displayObject` class,
and you can't access it using `displayObject.ob1`.
You need to pass a reference of *ob1* from your `MainClass` to `drawr`.
Or you probably meant `MainClass.ob1`? Since it is declared as a static variable in `MainClass`.

Comment: Nasty superior attitude aside, thanks.  That was helpful.  It was a static 'MainClass' object.

Comment: @user2671186 Haha okay, I will try to phrase my words in a nicer way next time. :)